# How to correctly get the time given the clock offset

Tags: c++

I want to create a timestamp (HHMMSSmmm) based on the system time and the clock offset (found from NTP servers). The issue I have is that sometimes the timestamp is not correctly set, e.g. when timestamp is 112400023‬ and the offset is -500, instead of setting it to ‭112359523‬ it becomes ‭112399523‬.

I thought to deduct the result by 40 seconds if this happens, but I was wondering if there is any better way to handle all cases, irrespective the offset?

These are the functions used in my case (where the GetMillisecondsTs() is the one that returns the timestamp).

```
void
Timestamp::gettimeofday(struct timeval* tp)
{
    // Note: some broken versions only have 8 trailing zero's, the correct epoch has 9 trailing zero's
    // This magic number is the number of 100 nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC)
    // until 00:00:00 January 1, 1970 
    static const uint64_t EPOCH = ((uint64_t)116444736000000000ULL);

    SYSTEMTIME  system_time;
    FILETIME    file_time;
    uint64_t    time;

    GetSystemTime(&system_time);
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&system_time, &file_time);
    time = ((uint64_t)file_time.dwLowDateTime);
    time += ((uint64_t)file_time.dwHighDateTime) << 32;

    tp->tv_sec = (long)((time - EPOCH) / 10000000L);
    tp->tv_usec = (long)(system_time.wMilliseconds * 1000);
}

uint32_t
Timestamp::GetMillisecondsTs(int offset)
{
    struct timeval unix;
    gettimeofday(&unix);

    int hour = (unix.tv_sec % 86400L) / 3600;
    int minute = (unix.tv_sec % 3600) / 60;
    int second = (unix.tv_sec % 60);
    int millisecond = (unix.tv_usec) / 1000; //keep only the first three decimals (since offset is 3 decimals)

    ostringstream _ss;
    _ss << std::internal << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << hour << std::internal << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << minute
        << std::internal << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << second << std::internal << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << millisecond;

    std::string _s = _ss.str();
    uint32_t _milliseconds = stoul(_s);
    _milliseconds += offset;

    return _milliseconds;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this. Add the `offset` before converting the time.

```
uint32_t
Timestamp::GetMillisecondsTs(int offset)
{
    struct timeval unix;
    gettimeofday(&unix);

    unix.tv_sec += offset / 1000;
    unix.tv_usec += (offset % 1000) * 1000;
    if (unix.tv_usec < 0) {
        unix.tv_sec--;
        unix.tv_usec += 1000000;
    }
    if (unix.tv_usec >= 1000000) {
        unix.tv_sec++;
        unix.tv_usec -= 1000000;
    }

    int hour = (unix.tv_sec % 86400L) / 3600;
    int minute = (unix.tv_sec % 3600) / 60;
    int second = (unix.tv_sec % 60);
    int millisecond = unix.tv_usec / 1000;

    return hour * 10000000 + minute * 100000 + second * 1000 + millisecond;
}
```

Note also that you don't need to convert to a string and back.

Comment: It falls in the same case as my approach. I think that since offset is in ms, needs to be expressed in respect to hours, minutes, seconds, and ms. For example, if ts=124000583 and offset = -1000, the right result would be 123959583, which means that I should express ms + offset = -1583, hence deduct 1 sec from second and 0 hours & minutes from the hour and minute, respectively. Or it could be applied in your approach but tv_sec should be updated. Thanks for the second part (string)

Comment: Yes, I did and this is what I get: timestamp 164659002 with offset -978, timestamp: 164699053 with offset -978. The second timestamp should be 164659053 instead.

Comment: I see. You need to compensate the millis. Pls try my updated version.

Comment: Yes it works, I am just trying to make it run for all offset values (e.g. if offset=-2000ms to deduct 2 seconds etc.). Thanks!